# How can I save the Entity what have a Entity List When Entity List is Null

Tags: hibernate, list, null, hibernate-cascade, ora-01400

It's my first question.
I hope I can get any hint here to solve my problem.

I use the hibernate for my application.
Here is my Code.

```
public class A {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<B> bList;
}

public class B{
    @ManyToOne(fech = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private A a;
}
```

And I expected that I can save the bList when I save the A automatically.
It works.

But there is a big problem when **bList is null**.
**hibernate try to save bList with A, even though bList is null**.

So it makes this Error.

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MYTEMPTB"."TB_B"."B_ID")

how can I solve it??
Please give me some hint.
Thanks.

Comment: initialize your list with empty one  
    `private List<B> bList=new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: You don't want bList to be null, or? Then you could use a prepersist callback to set the bList to something else than null before A is saved. Another option would be the initialization of bList using the new operator, although I would prefer the first proposal.

Comment: @MohamedNabli
yes. My List is initialize in empty state.
But I add some data into bList When I need. By using **addBList**method.
And this method work like this.

 if(this.bList == null){
   this.bList = new  ArrayList<BEtt>();
  }
  
  b.setA(this);
  
  bList.add(b);

Thank you for your attention. :-)

Comment: @Lonkey
It have a two diffrent case. Sometime It need some List of B entity. But sometime it doesn't need any data about B.
So, I tried to use the **prepersist**. but It's not working like my plan.
Maybe I need to try another proposal.
Thank for your advice. Have a nice day! ;-)